# How to search the highter CPU process between dates

Tags: cpu, process

Is possible to search which process has been the major or highter process between dates?
For instance: I need to search whats process has been the highter one the last month on my system.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this question could help you out: https://serverfault.com/questions/122697/check-history-of-cpu-memory-usage-in-ubuntu

Comment: Hi, thanks for your great advise, I've been able to find the historical events from CPU in my case that is most impportantly thing and the sar command is now my prefered =) so now I need to know which process or processes have been the ones that triggered the high CPU consumption, I need help with that now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I've found the real problem by using this command (previously I've used a lot of combinations):

*sar -u -f /var/log/sa/sa23 -s 05:00:00 -e 23:59:00 -d*

As per the output of this command-line the problem was a outstanding I/O request.

Thanks.